# encrypted docker container for desktop

Tags: docker, encryption, containers

I'm looking for a solution where I can run an app to an device in an ecrypted way, I mean user of that laptop should not be able to see the source code, just the running app. But it should be run on their device.

Is there any way to encrypt app running and use a key with expiration date, like windiws with licence? In my case is a little bit different, they should be much more limmited .

Thank you very much for the answers.

I didn't find any tool/framework for that.

Comment: No, it's not possible, and anyone who can run any `docker` command can all but trivially see the contents of all images and for that matter can trivially root the entire host.

Answer (score 0):

Docker cannot solve the issue, since everything in the container must be readable by the underlying OS.

With the command `docker save` the user can export the images content into a tar file. See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/

So you have to protect your app the same way you would protect it without docker.

First of all you should use a compiled language so the user cannot see the code directly. But even compiled code is not protected againts modification etc. To take it one step futher you could try to obfuscate the compiled binary.